# Props undefined error when using Apollo Client in Next.js project created with create-next-app

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, vercel

I'm experiencing an issue with Apollo Client in a project created using the create-next-app command in Next.js. I have installed the necessary packages and made the required configurations. However, when I try to fetch data in the getServerSideProps function, I'm getting the "props undefined" error, and the data is not being passed to the Home component.

In my project structure, I'm using Apollo Client to fetch data in the Home component and trying to retrieve the data using the getServerSideProps function. However, when I log the props object using console.log(props), it shows as undefined.

When I create the project using a different method (npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"), it works without any issues. However, I encounter this error when using the normal npx create-next-app command.

I have compared the package.json files and couldn't find any differences. I have also checked the other configuration files, but I don't see any problems.

I need assistance in identifying the cause of this issue and finding a solution. What could be causing this error when creating the project with the normal create-next-app command?

Thank you in advance!

```
// ./apollo-client.js

import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://countries.trevorblades.com",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;









// pages/index.js

import Head from "next/head";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "../apollo-client";

export default function Home({ countries }) {
  //console.log(countries);
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <div className={styles.grid}>
  {countries.map((country) => (
    <div key={country.code} className={styles.card}>
      <h3>{country.name}</h3>
      <p>
        {country.code} - {country.emoji}
      </p>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

// OR export async function getServerSideProps() {
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: gql`
        query Countries {
          countries {
            code
            name
            emoji
          }
        }
      `,
    });

    return {
      props: {
        countries: data.countries.slice(0, 4),
      },
   };
}
```

I initially encountered an 'Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')' error, and then realized that the issue was due to the empty content of the 'countries' variable. When I tried to log the content of the Home component to the console, I noticed that it was returning undefined.